# Run GitHub Action on start of self-hosted runner service

Tags: ubuntu, github, github-actions

Attempting to get our application to build/run the latest version *at boot* of my self-hosted runner (ubuntu). The runner service itself starts up with the system, but currently the only way to trigger our action is by pushing to the repository.

Of course, we could create a script that pulls/pushes arbitrarily to trigger the action. It also looks like there may be a way to trigger the action with a webhook. But it all seems heavy.

Is there no way to trigger an action at startup of the runner service itself?

Comment: We've opted to create a script file that hits github's [workflow_dispatch](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#workflow_dispatch) endpoint and runs as a service at boot.